# adjective vs perfect

Tags: grammar

> A lot of students are **present** at the meeting.
>
> A lot of students are **presented** at the meeting.

we can use **present** as adjective and verb.

when I should use adjective form and perfect form ?

Comment: Notice the different pronunciation: PREsent, preSENted. "PREsent" is not a verb, "preSENT" is.

Answer (score 2):

> A lot of students are present at the meeting.

*The students are present* means that they are there, they are attending the meeting. So there were a lot of students at the meeting.

> A lot of students are presented at the meeting.

Somebody presented the students (to the audience) at the meeting.

The two sentences have a completely different meaning. To be *present* means being somewhere, to be *presented* means to be introduced or to be given.

In both cases we can see present/presented as adjectival forms, by the way. A third form that you could use is *presenting*, the present participle of the verb. Then a lot of students were showing things at the meeting.

*Present* is a bit of a special case: the form *present* has a separate meaning in that form, as a common idiomatic adjective. This is not the case for most verbs!